Indentation problem inside the description environment
I have the following simple code
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[leftmargin=0.5cm,font=\normalfont\it\bfseries\underline]
\item[Case $1$.] 
\item[Case $2$.] 
\vskip 10pt
\item[]  According to Case $1$ and Case $2$, we must have $\pi_\mathbb{Q}(K)\neq 0$ 
 and $\pi_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(K) \neq 0$ which we consider in the following case.

\vskip 10pt
\item[Case $3$.] 
\end{description}
\end{document}

I need the following behaviour: I need the letter A of 'According' to be aligned with the letter C of 'Case'. When you run this code it seems that the paragraph is shifted a little bit to the right and that the second line of the paragraph is itself shifted to the right. How can I change this?
Another question: As a sort of abbreviation, is it possible to define the item as an option to be 'Case #N' where $N$ counts on positive integers?

Off-topic: (a) Please replace \it (Plain-TeX syntax) with \itshape (LaTeX syntax). (b) the \bfseries directive is redundant.

You want to define your own environment for this job.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe}

\newcounter{casedesc}
\newenvironment{casedesc}{%
  \setcounter{casedesc}{0}%
  \begin{description}[style=nextline,leftmargin=0pt,labelsep=0pt]
}{\end{description}}
\newcommand{\case}{%
  \stepcounter{casedesc}%
  \item[\normalfont\itshape\bfseries\underline{Case \textup{\thecasedesc}}]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{casedesc}
\case Some text for this case
\case Some text for this case

According to Case~1 and Case~2, we must have $\pi_\mathbb{Q}(K)\neq 0$ 
and $\pi_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(K) \neq 0$ which we consider in the following case.

\case Some text for this case
\end{casedesc}

\end{document}

I used showframe to see precisely what happens with the margins, remove it for your production version.

For variable representation of the case numbers, you can modify like below.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe}

\newcounter{casedesc}
\newenvironment{casedesc}[1][\arabic]{%
  \setcounter{casedesc}{0}%
  \let\casenumbering#1\relax
  \begin{description}[style=nextline,leftmargin=0pt,labelsep=0pt]
}{\end{description}}
\newcommand{\case}{%
  \stepcounter{casedesc}%
  \item[\normalfont\itshape\bfseries\underline{Case \textup{\casenumbering{casedesc}}}]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{casedesc}
\case Some text for this case
\case Some text for this case

According to Case~1 and Case~2, we must have $\pi_\mathbb{Q}(K)\neq 0$ 
and $\pi_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(K) \neq 0$ which we consider in the following case.

\case Some text for this case
\end{casedesc}

\begin{casedesc}[\Alph]
\case Some text for this case
\case Some text for this case

According to Case~1 and Case~2, we must have $\pi_\mathbb{Q}(K)\neq 0$ 
and $\pi_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(K) \neq 0$ which we consider in the following case.

\case Some text for this case
\end{casedesc}

\end{document}


After seeing the result, you'll hopefully realize that boldface plus italics plus underlining plus newline is quadruple emphasis.
Here's a version I'd prefer. I also add cleveref to see that you can refer to cases in a simpler way. Apart from \cref and the \label commands, the code hasn't changed.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}

\newlist{casedesc}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[casedesc]{
  wide=0pt,
  label=\textbf{\textit{Case} \arabic*.},
  ref=\arabic*,
}
\crefname{casedesci}{Case}{Cases}
\newcommand{\case}{\item}

\begin{document}

\begin{casedesc}
\case\label{cone} Some text for this case
\case\label{ctwo} Some text for this case

According to \cref{cone,ctwo}, we must have $\pi_\mathbb{Q}(K)\neq 0$ 
and $\pi_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(K) \neq 0$ which we consider in the following case.

\case Some text for this case
\end{casedesc}

\end{document}


For variable representation:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}

\newlist{casedesclist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[casedesclist]{
  wide=0pt,
}
\newenvironment{casedesc}[1][\arabic]{%
  \casedesclist[label=\textbf{\textit{Case} #1*.},ref=#1*,]%
}{\endcasedesclist}
\crefname{casedesclisti}{Case}{Cases}
\newcommand{\case}{\item}

\begin{document}

\begin{casedesc}
\case\label{cone} Some text for this case
\case\label{ctwo} Some text for this case

According to \cref{cone,ctwo}, we must have $\pi_\mathbb{Q}(K)\neq 0$ 
and $\pi_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(K) \neq 0$ which we consider in the following case.

\case Some text for this case
\end{casedesc}

\begin{casedesc}[\Alph]
\case\label{cthree} Some text for this case
\case\label{cfour} Some text for this case

According to \cref{cthree,cfour}, we must have $\pi_\mathbb{Q}(K)\neq 0$ 
and $\pi_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(K) \neq 0$ which we consider in the following case.

\case Some text for this case
\end{casedesc}

\end{document}



This is pretty cool. But I need the label to be dynamic, meaning that in some lists I use 'Case 1, Case 2, ...' and in some lists I use 'Case A, Case B, ...' . Is it necessary to redefine the description environment for the second list style?
Another question: Why 1 in \newlist{casedesc}{enumerate}{1}? What is its usage?

@HusseinEid I added the changes. The 1 means that you just want one level.

Thanks alot for your help.

Excuse me. I have one more requirement please about this great solution. I need the option nosep to be optional. i.e., I add it when I need it like \begin{casedesc}[nosep]. But I do not need it to be the default behaviour. How can I achieve this?


I need the letter A of 'According' to be aligned with the letter C of 'Case'.

Since you employ the enumitem package, I suggest you start the description environment with the options style=nextline and leftmargin=0cm.

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % for '\uline' macro

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=nextline,
                    leftmargin=0cm,
                    font=\itshape\uline]
\item[Case \upshape 1.]  
bla bla

\item[Case \upshape 2.] 
According to Case $1$ and Case $2$, we must have 
$\pi_\mathbb{Q}(K)\neq 0$ and $\pi_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(K) 
\neq 0$, which we consider in the following case.

\item[Case \upshape 3.] 
blu blu

\end{description}

\end{document}

